# MP3 file having trouble in built-in Music app or QuickTime Player, but does work in VLC

Tags: itunes, finder, audio, quicktime, mp3

I have an MP3 file that I listen to very often using the built-in Music app. Yesterday it stopped playing all together. I put my AirPods in and clicked the track & it didn't play. I tried another one, and it played perfectly.

I tried opening this MP3 in QuickTime Player and an error "The file isn’t compatible with QuickTime Player." came up. Quick Look in Finder refused to play it either, just showing the artwork of the track. I opened VLC to play the same file, and it played immediately.

Then I tried playing it in the Music app again today with my AirPods in, and it worked perfectly again, but still not in QuickTime Player, and also not in Quick Look via Finder.

How do I get it to play in QuickTime & Finder again? Thanks.